# Promise inside promise consistently

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have been tormented with this problem for 2 days, but did not dare to ask this question. I read a lot of documentation about promises and asynchronous functions. Perhaps the answer to this question will be useful to other users.

I want to call the details of a detail item in a list of items.

The `list` array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name: "A",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name: "B",
  },
  ...
]
```

The `one` data I want to call inside `list` array:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "url: "aaa",
  "props": ["a", "a", "a"]
}
```

[react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin) Promises:

```js
const list = dataProvider.getList(resource, params);
const one = (id: number) => dataProvider.getOne(resource, { id })
```

`dataProvider` return a Promise for an object with a `data` property.

I wrote a function that returns data in parallel:

```js
const data = async () => {
  const list = await dataProvider.getList(resource, params);
  const one = (id: number) => dataProvider.getOne(resource, { id });

  list.data = await Promise.all(
    list.data.map(async (item) => {
      const itemOne = await one(item.id);

      return {
        ...item,
        custom: {
          test: itemOne.data.url,
        },
      };
    })
  );

  return list;
};

console.log(data())
```

Now I'm [trying](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1271#issuecomment-514578455) to use a `reduce` instead of a `map`.

Please help me find the right solution or direction.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Sorry I incomprehensibly wrote a question. Corrected. I mean, when I do Promise.all, the first page load takes a lot of time, because all the elements load at the same time, I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. :-) I've updated my answer, I doubt you want to do those calls in series instead.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, Thanks, you saved some of my days. It seems that I initially did not correctly understand my problem.

Comment: My pleasure! I just noticed an error in the code examples in my answer that I've fixed, I forgot to change `getOne` to `getMany`... I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in this case, the promises are processed all at once, and not sequentially, so they make incredibly long page load time.
>
> Now I'm trying to use a reduce instead of a map.

It's unlikely that doing them in series (one after another) instead of in parallel (as you are now) would make anything faster; it's much more likely that it would make the page load take *longer*. But if you want to do those operations in series (one after another) rather than in parallel (all happening concurrently), `reduce` is over-complicated for that (and nearly everything else). Just use a `for-of` loop. I've included an example at the end of the answer.

I haven't used react-admin, but whenever getting a bunch of things from an API one-by-one is slow, I look to see if I can ask for them all at once instead. Looking at [the documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html), you can use `getMany` instead of `getOne`. Something like this:

```
const data = async () => {
  // Get the list
  const list = await dataProvider.getList(resource, params);

  // Get the items
  const items = await dataProvider.getMany(resource, { ids: list.data.map(({id}) => id) });
  // Extracting each `id` from the item to create the array −−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  // Add those to the list items
  list.data = list.data.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      custom: {
        test: items.data[index].url,
      },
    };
  });

  return list;
};
```

Note that that assumes that the data that comes back from `getMany` is in **the same order** as the `ids` array. The documentation seems to suggest that in the examples, but sadly doesn't actually *say* it.

If it turns out that it doesn't give them to you in the order you asked for them, you'll probably want to make a map keyed by `id`:

```
const data = async () => {
  // Get the list
  const list = await dataProvider.getList(resource, params);

  // Get the items
  const items = await dataProvider.getMany(resource, { ids: list.data.map(({id}) => id) });
  // Extracting each `id` from the item to create the array −−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  // Build the map of those items keyed by `id`
  const map = new Map(items.data.map(item => [item.id, item]));

  // Add those to the list items
  list.data = list.data.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      custom: {
        test: map.get(item.id).url,
      },
    };
  });

  return list;
};
```

---

Here's that `for-of` loop to do the work in series, but again, I think it's likely to make the problem *worse*, not better.

```
const data = async () => {
  const list = await dataProvider.getList(resource, params);
  const data = [];
  for (const item of list.data) {
      const itemOne = await dataProvider.getOne(resource, { id: item.id })
      data.push({
        ...item,
        custom: {
          test: itemOne.data.url,
        },
      });
  }
  list.data = data;
  return list;
};
```